# kernel package linux-headers-5.15.0-75-generic is not supported ... nvidia-535.113.01

Tags: nvidia

tried to fix the error below for some hours.

I like to install lambda stack ...
wget -nv -O- https://lambdalabs.com/install-lambda-stack.sh | sh -

Thanks a lot for suggestions.

```
**sudo apt --fix-broken install**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-535 (535.113.01-0lambda0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-535.113.01 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-535.113.01 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-535.113.01 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-75-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-75-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.15.0-75-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-75-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.113.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-535 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-535 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-535:
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (= 535.113.01-0lambda0.22.04.1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-535 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-75-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-535
 nvidia-driver-535
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

**sudo apt-get install -y initramfs-tools**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
initramfs-tools is already the newest version (0.140ubuntu13.4).
initramfs-tools set to manually installed.
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up nvidia-dkms-535 (535.113.01-0lambda0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Removing old nvidia-535.113.01 DKMS files...
Deleting module nvidia-535.113.01 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new nvidia-535.113.01 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-75-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-75-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.15.0-75-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-75-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.113.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-535 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-535 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-535:
 nvidia-driver-535 depends on nvidia-dkms-535 (= 535.113.01-0lambda0.22.04.1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-535 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-535 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-75-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-535
 nvidia-driver-535
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Did you do `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt autoremove` first?

Comment: Yes, getting the same error.

Comment: Since the 535 driver has been listed, I have never been able to install it successfully, so I went back to the 525 driver which works fine. I have 5.15.0-86-generic kernel. See if they work for you.

Comment: Thanks. I am relatively new to Linux. Is there an easy way to downgrade to 525?

Comment: Figured it out ... sudo apt list '*nvidia-driver*'
sudo apt-get purge '*nvidia*'
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525

Comment: Lambda stack successfully installed now. https://lambdalabs.com/lambda-stack-deep-learning-software

Comment: Please write what you did as an answer and then accept it as the correct answer. This way it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case was to roll back to the 525 driver, as there seems to be problems with the 535 driver for some users.

This can be done with the GUI be entering `sudo software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4` in a terminal, choosing the 525 driver and then `Apply changes` and once the changes have been applied, restart the computer.

OR this can be done entirely in a terminal

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`

`sudo reboot`

other useful commands

`sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` #show all drivers

`nvidia-smi` #show current driver